# Is it possible to create PointToPointDumbbell in ns3 but have different applications on the left nodes

Tags: ns-3

Is it possible to create PointToPointDumbbell in ns3 but have different applications on the left nodes such as OnOffApplication, UdpClientServer, and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Begin by creating the dumbbell topology using [PointToPointDumbbellHelper](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.33/doxygen/classns3_1_1_point_to_point_dumbbell_helper.html). Next, use the [GetLeft(uint32_t)](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.33/doxygen/classns3_1_1_point_to_point_dumbbell_helper.html#a33bf7a20ef9490831b5a73d51d2b3b21) and [GetRight(uint32_t)](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.33/doxygen/classns3_1_1_point_to_point_dumbbell_helper.html#ae2b4d86692b5df7542e228050b839a27) to get the individual Nodes on each side of the dumbbell.

Simply install the application you want on that Node using [Node::InstallApplication(Ptr<Application>)](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.33/doxygen/classns3_1_1_node.html#ab98b4fdc4aadc86366b80e8a79a53f47) or using [OnOffHelper::Install(Ptr<Node>)](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.33/doxygen/classns3_1_1_on_off_helper.html#ac2172f6ae83cd30cd3d3793d376d27dc) (or the Helper for whatever application it is you want to install).

Comment: Dear, the following code, where can I change the application exactly                                                
  
https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/red-vs-nlred_8cc_source.html

Comment: @AmarA.Mahawish look at lines 149 and 160.